# Shrink images to fit in flexbox with wrapping rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want an arbitrary number of images to shrink to fit inside a fixed-width div. 
It seems that flexbox is good for this purpose, but I can't seem to get it to work with wrapping multiple rows.

If I set `flex-flow` to `row wrap` and `flex` to `1 1 auto`, the images are too big.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
</div>
```

If I set `flex-flow` to just `row` or flex to `1 1 0`, the images don't wrap onto multiple lines:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the images expand enough to wrap as much as possible to fill the div, but not so much they break out of it?

Comment: "Shrink to fit" and "wrapping multiple rows" are mutually exclusive - you need to provide max/min widths or heights for the images otherwise they will just shrink down and never wrap.

Answer (score 2):

> If I set `flex-flow` to `row wrap` and `flex` to `1 1 auto`, the images are too big.

With `flex-basis: auto` your item will take the size of its content (the image, in this case). That's what you're getting in your first demo: The intrinsic width of the image.

> If I set `flex-flow` to just `row` or flex to `1 1 0`, the images don't wrap onto multiple lines.

With `flex-basis: 0` your item will ignore content size and distribute all space in the row evenly among items. That's what's happening in your second demo: It's creating three equal width items. As a result, there is no reason to wrap.

To control the size of flex items you need to define their `flex-basis`. Here's a rough sketch:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start; /* pack wrapping lines to the top */
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  margin: 5px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for an arbitrary number of images. I'm trying to avoid resorting to using javascript to calculate the flex-basis percentage.

Comment: I understand that the number of images is arbitrary. But how many items do you want per row? How is the browser supposed to know when to wrap?

Comment: That's a good question. I suppose it's basically a packing problem: I want to fill the container as much as possible, so I want to wrap as necessary to maximize the size of each image. But perhaps this is too much to ask of the browser...

Comment: The browser did *maximize the size of each image* (see your first example), but you said *the images are too big*. You need to make some decisions because the browser can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun.

```js
var container1 = document.querySelector('.container1'),
  container2 = document.querySelector('.container2'),
  img = container2.querySelectorAll('.container2 img'),
  width = 50,
  stop = false;

expand();

function expand() {
  for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].style.width = width + 'px';
  }
  if (stop) return;
  if (container2.clientHeight < container1.clientHeight) {
    width++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      expand()
    }, 10);
  } else {
    width--;
    stop = true;
    expand();
  }
}
```

```css
.container1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.container2 {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amusing! This is basically what I want the browser to automatically calculate for me...perhaps it's impossible with pure CSS, though.